# Is it possible to write text into a web page after it has loaded?

Tags: java

Let me get straight to an example to explain further.

```
final var socket = new java.net.ServerSocket(1234);
for (;;)
{
     try (final var client = socket.accept())
     {
          client.getOutputStream().write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n".concat(java.time.Instant.now().toString()).getBytes());
     }
}
```

When I now open my browser of choice (`Firefox` *cough*) I'll receive the current time and date. The question now is how I can write to that socket at a later point in time.

#### hypothetical solution

Here's something I already tried, but doesn't work at all.

```
final var socket = new java.net.ServerSocket(1234);
    for (;;)
    {
         try (final var client = socket.accept())
         {
              client.getOutputStream().write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n".concat(java.time.Instant.now().toString()).getBytes());
              client.getOutputStream().flush();
              Thread.sleep(1000L);
              client.getOutputStream().write("And another paragraph.".getBytes());
         } 
    }
```

The result is a web page loading for approximately a single second, printing out the following result (may vary due to different date and time on your end).

```
2019-01-19T18:19:15.607192500Z
And another paragraph.
```

Instead I would like the see something like that:

1. print out the current time and date.
2. wait a second without the content of the web page changing.
3. print out the next paragraph.

How would I go about implementing that?

Comment: what do you understand by "after initial connecting" ?

Comment: I'll be honest with you: I don't really know myself. Essentially, I just want to write data to the web page even after it is already showing something to the user (instead of just refreshing or loading).

Comment: This is something that you will want to do client-side, not server-side.

Comment: CSS preloader can help you ..

Comment: Hm. Could you elaborate on that point?

Comment: use like this: https://codepen.io/mimoYmima/pen/fisgL

Comment: Hm. that's not really what I'm going for. I want to do that in Java. And not just in the phase of the web page loading.

Comment: Javascript is the way to go for this one. You can delay the appearance of text. If I were you, I would google something like: how to send notifications to user after DOM has loaded. Or smth like that

Comment: @P.Soutzikevich You're probably right. Still, I'd love to see an implementation in pure Java.

Comment: @Theikun Well, I'm sure there's a way to do what you want, but your program would be much faster if you included client-side scripting. Nowadays RAM has become a commodity, as we see that the average pc has **>= 8GB**, that client-side scripting is strongly encouraged. It also helps get some processing load off the server(s)

Comment: The problem with doing this entirely on the server is that you can't control what the browser thinks your delay means. How does the browser know that your page is loading slowly because of a server commanded delay vs just a bad connection? The answer is that you have to tell the browser explicitly to show what it has, then wait for more. And that's exactly what a client side script is.

Comment: @PSoutzikevich. That sort of thinking is what makes so many sites useless on mobile. As a frequent mobile user myself (from a very crappy smartphone), I'm very happy with SO for being one of the sites that doesn't make foolish assumptions about "modern platforms".

Comment: Since this is server side code, you could go for Java Server Pages (JSP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible for the server to write text into a web page after it is loaded? Yes it definitely is, but these days I suspect it it is rarely done. I started web development in the 1990s and back then that was a pretty common technique. We used it to write live chat messages to browsers with no Javascript. These days Javascript is ubiquitous and powerful, so using client-side Javascript to update a page will be the best option in most cases.

That said, the technologies we used for writing server-side updates back then should still work now. I suspect the reason you don't see updates in your browser is because it doesn't know it should start displaying the page before everything is loaded. Using [chunked transfer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), a 1990s technology still supported by modern browsers, should resolve that. It it allows the server to indicate when a 'chunk' of data is complete and browsers will generally process each chunk immediately rather than wait for all the chunks to arrive.

The easiest way to use chunked transfer encoding is to use an HTTP library like [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/), then wrap your output stream in the appropriate class:

```
final var socket = new java.net.ServerSocket(1234);
for (;;)
{
  try (final var client = socket.accept())
  {
    var outputStream = new ChunkedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
    outputStream.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n".concat(java.time.Instant.now().toString()).getBytes());
    outputStream.flush();
    Thread.sleep(1000L);
    outputStream.write("And another paragraph.".getBytes());
  }
}
```